# Remove all links with a specific protocol with RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all links from a text and replace them with a subsitute that are starting with the protocols "example://" and "example_two://". All other links shall be untouched.

The following regex will replace all links despite of the fact that I limit the link types:

```
(\<a).+?(example|example_two)?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))(.+?)</a>+"
```

Has anyone a suggestion what is required to change the regex to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which characters are allowed in the link, this should work:

```
import re

link1 = r'<a href=example_two://path.com/to/something?and_some_parameters=1234&and_ano%20ther_one=asdf />'
link2 = r'<a> href="example_two://path.com/to/something?and_some_parameters=1234&and_another_one=asdf"</a>'

pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<before>(?:(?P<opening><a>)|<a).*)(?:example|example_two)://[a-zA-Z0-9_/.=%?&$:;#,<>]*(?P<after>.*(?(opening)</a>|/>))")

print(pattern.sub(r"\g<before>https://stackoverflow.com\g<after>", link1))
print(pattern.sub(r"\g<before>https://example.com\g<after>", link2))

# Prints:
# <a href=https://stackoverflow.com/>
# <a> href="https://example.com"</a>
```

This takes whatever is before the link and puts it in the `before` group, puts whatever comes after the link in the `after` group and then substitues the complete match in `pattern.sub`. The replacement is a concatenation of the matches in the `before` and `after` groups, with the replacement link in the middle.

What's more, the closing tag is conditioned on the opening tag. If the opening tag is `<a>`, the matched closing tag is `</a>`, otherwise a `/>` is matched.